# SenseNet.ExclusiveLock.MsSql component is missing

Tags: sensenet

After installing the latest version of Sensenet, the following error is displayed when application is started with debugging:

**SenseNet.ExclusiveLock.MsSql** component is missing.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: SenseNet.ExclusiveLock.MsSql component is missing.

Source Error:

```
Line 13:         protected override void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e, HttpApplication application)
Line 14:         {
Line 15:             base.Application_Start(sender, e, application);
Line 16: 
Line 17:             AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

Source File:  c:\users\administrator\source\repos\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\Global.asax.cs    Line:  15

```
[InvalidOperationException: SenseNet.ExclusiveLock.MsSql component is missing.]
   SenseNet.ContentRepository.RepositoryVersionInfo.IsComponentAllowed(SnComponentInfo component, Version installedComponentVersion) +217
   SenseNet.ContentRepository.RepositoryVersionInfo.CheckComponentVersions(SnComponentInfo[] components, Boolean release) +237
   SenseNet.Services.SenseNetGlobal.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e, HttpApplication application) in C:\agent-02\_work\2\s\src\Services\SenseNetGlobal.cs:166
   WebApplication4.MvcApplication.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e, HttpApplication application) in c:\users\administrator\source\repos\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\Global.asax.cs:15
   SenseNet.Portal.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\agent-02\_work\2\s\src\Services\Global.cs:15

[HttpException (0x80004005): SenseNet.ExclusiveLock.MsSql component is missing.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +10107111
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +123
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +181
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +228
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +314

[HttpException (0x80004005): SenseNet.ExclusiveLock.MsSql component is missing.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10087352
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +99
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +263
```

I followed installation instructions closely and no build errors were reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a previous version of sensenet and you upgraded the NuGet packages, am I correct? It seems that this combination does not work, because the component above is installed automatically by the new infrastructure - which is not compatible with your version. The only solution I see here is to downgrade the packages to their older versions (at least last August, maybe older). SenseNet has changed a lot since we moved to .Net Core, and there are some incompatibilities with the .Net Framework libraries. Please consider taking a look at the new "sensenet as a service" solution that will free you from the upgrade hassle.

Comment: I tried to upgrade from the previous version, but gave up on it. Since my client requires handling their data on premise, I tried fresh installation from scratch. My plan was to eventually import customer data into the latest version of Sensenet (at least the latest published on Github).

I created a new project, installed Sensenet.Services.Install NuGet package, made required changes to the code, built the solution, and performed installation through SnAdmin.

How cumbersome is to downgrade the packages in order to make it work?

Comment: Downgraded to v7.7.1 and it it working! Thanks!